# Perform operations on the output of find command with -exec options

Tags: linux, bash, find, gzip, zgrep

I want to perform operations on the files found by the find command which already has a -exec option.

```
find . -type f -exec zgrep -li "4168781103" {} +
```

Output:

```
./results/Query_20200501_18_32_00_msisdn_14168781103_detail.csv
./results/Query_20200501_18_32_02_msisdn_14168781103_summary.csv
./results/Query_20200501_18_32_02_msisdn_14168781103_detail.csv
./results/Query_20200501_18_32_04_msisdn_14168781103_summary.csv
./results/Query_20200501_18_32_04_msisdn_14168781103_detail.csv
./results/Query_20200501_18_32_51_msisdn_14168781103_summary.csv
./results/Query_20200501_18_32_51_msisdn_14168781103_detail.csv
./results/Query_20200501_18_36_03_msisdn_14168781103_summary.csv
./2311/2020_05/01/18/2311.TRL_20200501180400114.c.5.3.38.0.trl.gz
./2311/2020_05/01/18/trlindex.db
./2311/2020_05/01/18/2311.TRL_20200501180500115.c.5.3.38.0.trl.gz
./2311/2020_05/01/18/2311.TRL_20200501180600116.c.5.3.38.0.trl.gz
./2311/2020_05/01/18/2311.TRL_20200501180700117.c.5.3.38.0.trl.gz
./2311/2020_05/01/18/2311.TRL_20200501181000118.c.5.3.38.0.trl.gz
./2311/2020_05/01/18/2311.TRL_20200501183000119.c.5.3.38.0.trl.gz
./2311/2020_05/01/18/2311.TRL_20200501183100120.c.5.3.38.0.trl.gz
./2311/2020_05/01/18/2311.TRL_20200501183200121.c.5.3.38.0.trl.gz
./2323/2020_05/01/18/2323.TRL_20200501180400296.4.3.18.0.trl.gz
```

I found these files containing the key string `4168781103` using find with `-exec` option, Now i want to print the contents of all the files found below ending with file name `.trl.gz` only or run a search on these files....

Comment: `-name '*.trl.gz'` before the `-exec`, Note the single quotes `'` are not optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to process only the *.trl.gz* files in the end, you can focus `find` on them in the first place :

> find . -type f **-name "*.trl.gz"** -exec zgrep -li "4168781103" {} +

Then for further processing, you can pipe through `xargs`.

Printing :

```
find . -type f **-name "*.trl.gz"** -exec zgrep -li "4168781103" {} + **| xargs cat ...**
```

Further search :

```
find . -type f **-name "*.trl.gz"** -exec zgrep -li "4168781103" {} + **| xargs zgrep ...**
```

Or use command substitution in your POSIX-compliant shell:

```
cat $(find . -type f -name "*.trl.gz" -exec zgrep -li "4168781103" {} +)
```

Comment: Thanks @Hoel Gulicher, Actually xargs utility is not available on my production system, Is there any other way to do it.

Comment: Adding shell substitution alternative as proposed by [Devon](https://superuser.com/users/739813/devon).